# Define procs whose name is from a macro parameter using MASM 64

Tags: assembly, macros, x86-64, masm, masm64

Is it possible to define procs where the name is derived from the inputs in a macro, using MASM 64? (ml64.exe)

Eg, something similar to below, where @(value) just places the 'value' in to the source.

```
proc_creator macro name, value
    foo_@(name) proc
        mov rax, value
        ret
    foo_@(name) endp
endm

proc_creator "example", 1
proc_creator "example2", 2

...

    call foo_example2
    ; use rax
```

So calling the macro twice defines two procs, `foo_example` and `foo_example2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the operator to use is `& &`, eg:

```
proc_creator macro name, value
    foo_&name& proc
        mov rax, value
        ret
    foo_&name& endp
endm

proc_creator "example", 1
proc_creator "example2", 2

...

    call foo_example2
    ; use rax
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-logical-and-masm?view=msvc-170